# How to display the "const" c++ specifier in Enterprise Architect operation parameters

Tags: c++, enterprise-architect

I know I can set the *Fixed Value* property for operation parameters and the online help says that it corresponds to the `const` c++ keyword, but whatever I try, I cannot get it to display on my class diagram.

How can I achieve that?

Edit: 
I know I can just write const before my parameter type, but I want to know if there is a cleaner way to do it (like for the option to automatically add & or * when we tag a parameter as inout or out).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `'Fixed'` checkbox to render `const` (reference) parameters. `const` isn't a *decoration* that appears in UML parameter syntax notation:

[image]

The UML notation doesn't reflect this:

[image]

You can specify your parameter type to be a const reference though:
[image]

The rendered output looks like this:
[image]